# Compare first column with others three columns. Display unmatch data in last column

Tags: excel

I have the table below. Basically column A is the master data.
Column B, C and D will contain the some data in column A. Column B, C and D can have common data.

I want to compare data column A to column B,C and D.
In column Result, display all unmatch data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub MissingItems()
    Dim N As Long, I As Long, J As Long, V As String
    Dim r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    J = 1
    For I = 1 To N
        V = Cells(I, 1).Value
        Set r = Nothing
        Set r = Range("B:D").Find(V, After:=Range("B1"))
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Cells(J, 5).Value = V
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this "big" array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10;SMALL(IF(NOT(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$2;$A$1:$A$10)+COUNTIF($C$1:$C$3;$A$1:$A$10)+COUNTIF($D$1:$D$2;$A$1:$A$10));ROW($A$1:$A$10)-ROW($A$1)+1;"");ROW(A1)))
```

Write the formula wherever you want to obtain the first an then copy down to obtain the others.

This is an array formula so dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","

This one is smaller and still works:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10;SMALL(IF(NOT(COUNTIF($B$1:$D$3;$A$1:$A$10));ROW($A$1:$A$10)-ROW($A$1)+1;"");ROW(A1)))
```